# grunt usemin - concat + uglify sourcemap

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify, grunt-usemin

I'm trying to minify my js and css files but i have a problem with source map files.

My app is an **angularjs** app and before the *usemin* i need to generate the angular *templates.js* files and concatenate all *js* files.

my `index.html` is

```
  <!-- build:js  js/vendor.min.js -->
    <script src="../vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../vendor/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="../vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../vendor/es5-shim/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../vendor/json3/lib/json3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../vendor/http/http.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../vendor/fs/dist/fs.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../vendor/parse/parse.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../vendor/event/dist/js/event.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../vendor/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js  js/app.min.js -->
    <script src="../.tmp/concat/app.concat.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Now the concat task is concatenating my source files

```
 concat: {
            options:{
                sourceMap:true
            },
            js: {
                src: [
                    '<%= config.src %>/**/module/**/*.js',
                    '<%= config.src %>/**/svcs/**/*.js',
                    '<%= config.src %>/**/ctrls/**/*.js',
                    '<%= config.src %>/**/dirs/**/*.js',
                    '<%= config.src %>/**/filters/**/*.js',
                    '<%= config.src %>/**/model/**/*.js',
                    '<%= config.src %>/**/prvdrs/**/*.js',
                    '<%= config.tmp %>/concat/app.templates.js'
                ],
                dest: '<%= config.tmp %>/concat/app.concat.js'
            }
    },
```

and the *sourcemap (app.concat.js.map)* file is correctly generated.

The generated sourcemap is input of the uglify:generated task

```
uglify:{
            generated:{
                options:{

                    sourceMap:{
                        includeSources: true
                    },
                    sourceMapIn:'.tmp/concat/app.concat.js.map'

                }
            }
        },
```

finally this is the registeredTask for grunt

```
grunt.registerTask('build',[
        'ngtemplates:app',
        'concat:js',
        'copy_assets',
        'less:dev',
        'useminPrepare',
        'concat:generated',
        'uglify:generated',
        'cssmin',
        'usemin'
    ]);
```

The task is runned correctly, anyway the Chrome developer tool doesn't allow me to set brekpoints where I want

as requested here the ngtemplates task

```
ngtemplates: {
            app:        {
                cwd: '<%= config.src %>',
                src: ['**/*.html','!<%= config.src %>/templates/*.html'],
                dest: '<%= config.tmp %>/js/app.templates.js'
            }
        },
```

Comment: Please post your `ngtemplates` task as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
uglify:{
        generated:{
            options:{

                sourceMap:{
                    includeSources: true
                },
                sourceMapIn:'.tmp/concat/app.concat.js.map'

            }
        }
    },
```

this won't work because it will ignore anything within "generated" options.

try to rename it to "gruntisdead" or something else. however the "generated" task may run anycase and rewrite your output. so to avoid it just stop use grunt and go to gulp, webpack or something more modern